# Unable to load CSS file within nodeJS app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I have an app that I followed from a tutorial for the backend in nodeJS and Express. My connection to MongoDB via Mongoose is working. However, I've been trying to add a front-end- at the moment- just a simple html/ejs/css form. My endpoints are loading in localhost but only the html/ejs is rendering. My css file shows as plain code at `http://localhost:3000/styles.css` but isn't loading so I'm just getting plain html/ejs. I'm using VS Code. Here's my relevant code:

App.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const product = require('./routes/product.routes'); // Imports routes for the products
const app = express();
var path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
app.use('/product', product);

let port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up and running on port number ' + port);
});
```

Product.routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Require the controllers WHICH WE DID NOT CREATE YET!!
const product_controller = require('../controllers/product.controller');


// a simple test url to check that all of our files are communicating correctly.
router.get('/', product_controller.start);

router.get('/test', product_controller.test);

router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);

router.get('/:book', product_controller.product_details);

router.put('/:book/update', product_controller.product_update);

router.delete('/:book/delete', product_controller.product_delete);

module.exports = router;
```

Product.controller.js

```
const Product = require('../models/product.model');

//Simple version, without validation or sanitation

exports.start = function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: './views' })}


exports.test = function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', { root: './views' })}
```

Index.ejs

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/public/styles.css'/>
    <base href="/"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>BookBooker</h1>
      <h2>A library app for personal use.</h2>
      <form action="/create" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Writer" name="name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Book" name="book" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    <script src="app.js" type="module" type='text/javascript'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My file structure looks like:

```
CRUD folder
-app.js
-package.json
-package-lock.json
-controller folder
--product.controller.js
-public folder
--styles.css
-routes folder
--product.routes.js
-views folder
--index.html
--index.ejs
```

Apologies if it's obvious- I'm super new to this. As you can see, I've tried static files, paths, CORS, and lots of combinations of file routing but I'm getting myself in a big muddle. I've considered caching but the css isn't showing in Chrome, Edge or Incognito mode either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you include `app.js`  as a `<script>` element in your HTML page? That seems to be your _backend_ Javascript code, which has no place in the HTML page (frontend).

Comment: Thank you, Heiko. That was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part- I realise now that space is for my front-end js which I haven't got round to yet. I've deleted the script tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/public/styles.css'/>
```

write

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/styles.css'/>
```

The `public` folder name is *not* part of the stylesheet URL, it is just the folder where `express.static` looks for files.

Comment: WOOP! WOOP! Thank you, Heiko. Yes, this works. Cheers for taking the time to answer. I'll upvote/mark as the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS showing as plain text may be caused by a wrong Content-type in the header. The browser is interpreting it as a plain text file, instead of handling it as CSS. Before you send the response, you can set response headers in your controller like:

```
res.header('Content-type', 'text/css');
```

See [Express Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#setHeaders)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe. But it didn't work. Good idea though.

Comment: O, okay. Did you also check the response header in the networking tab in the devtools of your browser?

Comment: I've got ```Accept``text/css,*/*;q=0.1```. Does that look okay? I'm also getting a 304 status. HOWEVER, in localhost:3000/product/styles.css I'm now getting the contents of my database- so JSON. Which would explain why the css isn't getting read. But now the question is why is my product/styles.css showing this JSON and not the contents of the css file...

Comment: The 304 and content-type are okay. 304 means that the content has not changed since the previous request.